# Create JSON/GSON from json file within a jar

Tags: json, jar, gson

I use Google's `GSON` library to generate GSON/JSON objects.

However, now I have the problem that I need to create a GSON object for a file within a jar.
I can get a `InputStream`, `BufferedReader` or `Properties` from the json file I want to parse to an GSON object, however the `Gson().toJson()` then `Gson().fromJson` can't generate a GSON object from any of the above mentioned.

So, how would I access a json file within a jar and pass it to the GSON library to get a GSON file?

Right now I have something along this line:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JarFile jar;
        jar = new JarFile("path.jar");
        InputStream inputStream = jar.getInputStream(jar.getEntry("file.json"));
}
```

Comment: Are you saying a json file is inside the jar and you want to parse it into java objects with gson? Sorry the question is a little unclear.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Is the jar on your class path?

Comment: No, it's not. The jar is inside a folder, which is next to the 'src' folder (using Eclipse).

Comment: Have you tried the getjarentry method instead? What you're doing looks basically right

Comment: The thing is, I can get the InputStream, so the path is correct. However, I don't know which format the GSON library needs to create the GSON object. As I mentioned, it doesn't work with InputStream, BufferedReader nor Properties.

Comment: It works with reader and class type to deserialize

Comment: BufferedReader? I get null values if I pass a BufferedReader, where I didn't get one before (when parsing the json file outside the jar).